# how to make 2 values textfield inserted into one column in database in php?

Tags: php

i have a problem..
what i want is..i have a form with 2 textfield. i want the value after we insert data into it..the data will insert into database in one column..but how to do it?sory for my bad english..:'(

```
<td bgcolor="#A4DDED"> <strong>DL</strong>  
 <input name="NF1" type="text" size="10" id="NF1" />
 <strong> / </strong>
 <label>
 <input name="Y2" type="text" id="Y2" size="10" />
 </label></td>
```

i have 2 textfield with difference name or id.. how to make the value insert into database in one column?
..we will insert some value to it and it will insert into database 
|DL____/_____|

example: |DL 2909/2034|  <--the data will inserted after we insert at form page*

Comment: why do you want it inserted in single column? And if it happens how you will retrieve them?

Comment: Show us some code on how you've tried to do it so far.

Comment: Database? Database table? Database columns? Maybe any details at all would be great?

Answer (score 0):

you need to concatenate the two input fields and insert into the single column

```
$concat = $variable1 . $variable2;
```

then insert the concat variable in one column

Comment: $concat = $variable1 . $variable2; <--WHERE SHOULD I PUT?

Answer (score 0):

Just add it together in a string and then add the string to the database.

```
$concat = '|DL ' . $_POST['NF1'] . '/'. $_POST['Y2'] . '|';
```

if NF1 = 2909 and Y2 = 2034 the output will be:

```
|DL 2909/2034|
```